# Is it rational or not?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

I have two interesting question :

Is this number rational or not:
$$0.F_{1}F_{2}F_{3}...$$, where $F_{i}$ - Fibonacci number.

And is this number rational or not:
$$0.p_{1}p_{2}...$$

Comment: Is it $0.F_1F_2F_3\ldots$ and $0.p_1p_2\ldots$ where the $p_i$'s re presumably the prime numbers ?

Comment: @Shailesh yes, that is

Comment: The question is not well-posed. With $0.F_1 F_2 F_3\ldots$ do you mean $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{F_n}{10^n}$ or the number we get by concatenating all Fibonacci numbers? They are different things.

Comment: One of Jack's options is rational.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I mean this number: $a = 0.1123581321...$, where you could see Fibonacci numbers

Comment: Then the second one is the [Copeland–Erdős constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant), known to be irrational.

Comment: @Watson thanks, didn't hear about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both numbers are irrational. It's clear that neither number has the decimal expansion eventually consisting of only zeroes, so if we prove that they have arbitrarily long trails of zeroes, we will get our result.

Let's start with the latter number, known as, as Watson mentioned in a comment, [Copeland–Erdős constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant). We have $\gcd(1,10^{n+1})=1$, so by [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), there are infinitely many primes $p$ satisfying $p\equiv 1\pmod{10^{n+1}}$. But this prime has $n$ consecutive zeroes in its decimal expansion, namely second, third,..., $n+1$-th.

As for the former number, I will use the following lemma, which I leave for you to try to prove it:

> For any number $k$, there is a number $m$ such that $k\mid F_m$.

(hint for proof: consider sequence $(F_m\mod k,F_{m+1}\mod k)$. Using pigeonhole principle, show that this sequence eventually repeats, and hence it's periodic (not only eventually periodic). Lastly recall $F_0=0$)

Now let's use the lemma with $k=10^n$. Then $F_m$ will contain a trail of $n$ zeroes, namely its last $n$ digits.

Comment: You might want to help Neal Sloane out: http://oeis.org/A031324